# Contradiction in IEEE 1800-2009 LRM wrt `timescale

Tags: system-verilog, hdl

IEEE 1800-2009 Systemverilog LRM says on p21. The bold portions seem contradictory. Which is it?

> If a timeunit is not specified within a module, program, package, or
>   interface definition, then the time unit shall be determined using the
>   following rules of precedence:
>
> a) If the module or interface definition is nested, then the time unit
>   shall be inherited from the enclosing module or interface (programs
>   and packages cannot be nested).
>
> b) **Else, if a `timescale directive has been previously specified
>   (within the compilation unit), then the time unit shall be set to the
>   units of the last `timescale directive.**
>
> c) Else, if the compilation-unit scope specifies a time unit (outside
>   all other declarations), then the time unit shall be set to the time
>   units of the compilation unit.
>
> d) Else, the default time unit shall be used.
>
> **The time unit of the compilation-unit scope can only be set by a
>   timeunit declaration, not `timescale directive.** If it is not
>   specified, then the default time unit shall be used.

Answer (score 1):

Rules a-d are referring to the scope **within** a module, program, package, or interface. The last sentence you quoted refers to the scope outside that. For example

```
`timescale 1ms / 1 ns

task delay;
#1; // default time unit
endtask
module top;

initial #1 delay(); // uses `timescale

endmodule
```